# Continuous bijective way of representing a line on a plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

Is there a function $f(a,b)$ which maps ordered pairs to lines in a plane in a continuous, bijective manner?

Here is the definition I am using for the limit with lines: a sequence of lines $L(1), L(2), \dots$ is said to approach another line $L$ if, for any point $p$ on $L$, the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the distance between $p$ and $L(n)$ is $0$.

If there is no such function, can anyone think of a proof?

Comment: Which topology do you put on the target set?

Comment: (a,b) |-> {y = ax+b} ?

Comment: MO is intended for research-level questions.  The FAQ lists a number of websites that are more appropriate for elementary questions (for instance, math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Allen Your parametrization leaves out vertical lines.

Comment: That function is not surjective; it won't hit any vertical lines.

Comment: Well I guess yrudoy doesn't specifically ask for his function to be surjective...

Comment: Or, what about (a,b) -> {y=0}?

Comment: @Allen Knutson: As Steven and Simon pointed out, (a,b) |-> {y = ax+b} is not one to one. It misses the case y=c.

@Steven: You are completely correct; my apologies. By 1:1, I meant that the function was bijective, but apparently the standard defenition of 1:1 is injective, so that is my fault. I edited the problem so that it was correct.

Comment: @yrudoy: The map `$(a,b)\mapsto\{y=ax+b\}$` *is* 1-1! You mean it is not surjective. (I guess you are thinking of "1:1 correspondence")

Comment: Really, the key issue is how are you assigning a topology to the set of lines. There may be a question here, but only after you address this issue.

Comment: @yrudoy: also, you meant to say that Allen's parametrization misses lines of the form x=c, not y=c.

Comment: @Thierry Zell: Yes. Sorry.

@Andres Caicedo: I suppose that since we don't have a definition of 'limit' for lines, 'continuous' would not be rigorously defined . Here is the definition I am using: 

a sequence of lines L(1), L(2), etc. is said to approach another line L if, for any point p on L, the limit as n goes to infinity of the minimum distance between p and L(n) is 0.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/877/continuous-bijective-way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such bijection.

A line in the plane is almost the same as a plane through the origin in 3-space (by intersecting with the plane at height 1), except there's one plane through the origin that doesn't give you a line (the z=0 plane). So the space of lines in the plane is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2$ minus a point: an open mobius strip! So the question is asking if there is a continuous bijection from the open disk $D$ to the open mobius strip $M$. [Invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) implies that a continuous bijection between manifolds of the same dimension is a homeomorphism. $D$ and $M$ are not homeomorphic, so there cannot be a continuous bijection between them.

Comment: (copied from meta) Very nice, but I believe a continuous map needs to be proper for the induced function on one-point compactifications is also continuous. So you have shown that there is no proper map of the desired type, but I think maybe a bit more is required to show there is no continuous map at all?

Comment: You're right. I don't see a fix right now.

Comment: Invariance of domain says that a continuous, one-to-one map of manifolds (without boundary) is a homeomorphism onto its image, so I think that finishes the proof because $D$ (contractible) is not homeomorphic to the open mobius strip (not contractible).

Comment: (there should have been an "of the same dimension" after the word "manifolds")

Comment: Very nice. I'll edit the answer now. I was sitting around trying to prove invariance of domain. Is there an easy way to see that a continuous bijection $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Basic idea of invariance of domain (from http://books.google.com/books?id=ruSqmB7LWOcC&pg=PA252#v=onepage): Say $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is bijective continuous. Let $B$ be a ball with boundary $S$. $S$ is homeomorphic to its image (because it's compact), so it breaks $\mathbb R^n$ into two open components, a bounded set $U$ and an unbounded set $W$ (this is where the work goes). The image of $B$ is compact, so bounded, so the image of the interior of $B$ is $U$ (the complement of $B$ cannot hit any of the points of $U$ since it has to hit $W$ and it is connected). So $f$ is open.

Comment: Small point: if n=1 you get three open components. Everything still works.